# Please suggest a jQuery slider plugin which one has this functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slider

I tried all the jQuery slider plugins out there.
But none of them has the functionality what I expect.
Check this image.
[image]

I need a slider like this. I mean the middle image have to be zoomed when slide. Please suggest a good jQuery plugin.

Comment: Those aren't called sliders. The usual term is 'Carousel'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingBoxes/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jcoverflip.com/features

Answer (score -1):

Have a look into the [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) plugin.

It's extremely well supported and fully featured.